# What is the story of the earth's milking during previous Manvantaras?

Tags: scripture, manvantara, bhumi

The 2nd Canto of Brahmanda Purana mentiones that the milking of the earth at diffrent Manvantaras:-

> 15a. Thereafter, in. the Svāyambhuva Manvantara (the Earth -was milked) after making Svāyambhuva Manu the calf. All types of plants were the milky yield.
>
> Thereafter, when the Svārociṣa Manvantara arrived, the Earth was milked after making Svārociṣa, the calf. The plants and food-grains were the milky yield.
>
> 15b-16a. In the Uttama (Manvantara) the earth was milked by intelligent Devabhuja after making Manu the best calf and the (milk-yield was) all crops.
>
> 16b-I7a. Again during the fifth Manvantara calíed Tāmasa, the earth was milked again by Balabandhu after makiny Tāmasa (Manu) as the calf.
>
> 17b-18a. It is reported that when the sixth Manvantara of Cāriṣṭava (Cāriṣṇava in Vā. P.) arrived, the Earth was milked by Purāṇa for the calf Cāriṣṭava. ***(I think Caristava is Raivata Manu's another name and sixth is the mistranslation of fifth)***
>
> 18b-19a. When the Cākṣuṣa Manvantara arrived, in that Manvantara, the Earth was milked by Purāṇa (?) after making Cākṣuṣa, the calf.
>
> 19b-20a. When the Cākṣuṣa Manvantara had elapsed and the Vaivasvata Manvantara arrived, the Earth was milked by the son of Vena ***(Prithu)***. How it was milked has already been recounted to you by me.

The current milking of earth by Prithu is well-known. But, what about the previous milking of earth during previous Manvantaras? Does any other scriptures mention about that?